# Django bulk_create ignore_conflicts=True leaks memory

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, bulkinsert, django-celery

We are using **Django 2.2, python 3.6 and mysql 5.6** for scheduling data intensive jobs.

Memory is increasing over time for a long running job. **DEBUG=False** in settings.py

#### why use ignore_conflicts?

we set up a unique key for the table, so **ignore_conflicts** can filter out those records already in the table.

simple code like this

```
for record_batch in readFromSomewhere(batch_size):
    for record in record_batch:
        product = parse(record)
        product_list.append(product)
    
    # memory increase and leak
    Product.objects.bulk_create(product_list, ignore_conflicts=True) 
    
    # memory does not increase
    #Product.objects.bulk_create(product_list)  

    #db.reset_queries()
    #gc.collect()
```

I read a lots of stackoverflow post and put `gc.collect()` and `django.db.reset_query()`, but it does not prevent the increase.
If I use `Product.objects.bulk_create(products)`, memory does not increase.
but if I use `Product.objects.bulk_create(products,ignore_conflicts=True)` the memory increase over time.

the batch size is very small, around 100.
I notice if the batch size is smaller, which means the number of bulk_create calls is larger, memory increases faster. If the batch size is larger, then memory increase slower.

Any thoughts to release the memory after batch created(ignore_conflict=True) into db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause has been found by digging into the memory.
we were using mysqlclient==1.3.14 package. this package contains warning checks.
those warning messages were saved to memory and never be garbaged collected.

they directly removed all the warning checks from the package after new release.
so after upgrading to mysqlclient==1.4.4, the memory becomes stable.