Memory Leak When Using Django Bulk Create
I have the following code that constantly checks an API endpoint and then if needed, adds the data to my Postgres database.
Every iteration of this loop is leaking memory in the postgresql\operations.py file.
Im not sure what data is still being referenced and isnt clearing, so realistically what could be causing this issue?
class DataObject(models.Model):
    raw_data = models.TextField()
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    
    def post_process(self):
        data = json.loads(self.raw_data)       
        self.name = data['name']
        
def do_from_schedule():

    api = API()
    loads = api.grab_all_data()
    del api

    datas_to_create = []

    for load in loads:
        data = DataObject()
        data.raw_data = json.dumps(load)
        data.post_process()
        datas_to_create.append(data)

    DataObject.objects.bulk_create(datas_to_create, ignore_conflicts=True, batch_size=200)

    del datas_to_create

    gc.collect()
    
   
while True:
    do_from_schedule()
    time.sleep(5)

Here are the results of tracemalloc. Theres a consistent, and unending memory leak.

#1: postgresql\operations.py:322: 156.9 KiB
return cursor.query.decode()

#1: postgresql\operations.py:322: 235.3 KiB
return cursor.query.decode()

#1: postgresql\operations.py:322: 313.7 KiB return cursor.query.decode()

#1: postgresql\operations.py:322: 392.0 KiB return cursor.query.decode()

#1: postgresql\operations.py:322: 470.4 KiB return cursor.query.decode()


I found this for someone using MySql
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65098227/8521346
But im not sure how to even test/ fix this if it was the issue with the postgres client.
--Edit--
The proported duplicate question had nothing to do with, nor fixed the issue. I already included reset_queries() in my code way before posting. This issue is strickly related to bulk_create

If you remove ignore_conflicts from the query, does the memory still increase?

It seems to have helped, but I depend on the database to reject the duplicates for me for performance reasons. Is there something further that can be done to allow for ignore_conflicts without the memory issue? @LordElrond

"I already included reset_queries() in my code way before posting" we don't see it in your code though? And that cursor.query.decode() that you believe is where the leak is the same thing which is the issue in the other question.

@Bigbob556677 Can you update your question to include a minimal, reproducible example?  Also, please include the versions of Django an psycopg2 you are using.

If the issue truly persists after setting DEBUG=False, then there is either a bug in your code, or a bug in Django.  Since we can't reproduce the problem, it's impossible to tell.

@AbdulAzizBarkat reset_queries wasnt included because it didnt help and was consiquently removed. removing ignore_conflicts seems to fix it as the attached answer shows, but that is for MySql. Also the referenced duplicate has nothing to do with bulk_create.

@LordElrond yea it does, but removing ignore_conflicts fixes it, but im using ignore_conflicts as a gate for duplicate values. Also this is running from a management command that runs indefinitly in the background. Not sure if thats relevant.

If reset_queries didn't work for you don't just say it didn't work but rather show that you used it properly to demonstrate that the answer for the duplicate doesn't work for you. Also what's the value of your DEBUG setting? Please [edit] your question for these points.

Also consider the resources being used if you have enough, can be that your bulk inserting data more than the memory it can handle, server also has configurable memory limit so your program does not consume all memory leaving room for the server to stay functional.

@AbdulAzizBarkat reset_queries has nothing to do with the question, and shouldnt even be considered in the conversation. Thats why i didnt include it, nor the other 10 things i tried to make it work. We've narrowed it down specifically to batch_create

@MarkMorganMiranda the server has 64gb of ram, its just a very slow, constant memory leak. but the process runs 24/7 so it does get rather bad eventually

How did you try to use reset_queries, did you run it in your loop or did you just run it once?

@AbdulAzizBarkat it ran right after the bulk create on each loop.

The return cursor.query.decode() comes from the last_executed_query method, this isn't usually called by anything within Django at all unless DEBUG is True, in which case as the duplicate I had linked mentions the queries are collected into a log (Specifically a deque). Normally when you call reset_queries this log should be cleared and then eventually your memory should be freed up. If that is not happening you likely have something trying to keep track of DB queries which calls the same last_executed_query method. In which case you haven't given us a [mre]

@AbdulAzizBarkat cool ill check. thanks. this is running from a management command. Django Silk may be doing something with it. since thats used to track queries.

@Bigbob556677
Would doing it async possible for your case scenario or you need that data immediately after insert? To have the resources management done properly Django has provided abulk_create "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.abulk_create" which is Async version of bulk_create

I can try it, the actual part where the insert is being done is sync though, the api end point is async. @MarkMorganMiranda
